# Identifying the data type of an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, user-input

I am trying to print the data type of a user input and produce a table like following:

```
ABCDEFGH = String
1.09 = float
0 = int
true = bool
```

etc.

I'm using Python 3.2.3 and I know I could use `type()` to get the type of the data but in Python all user inputs are taken as strings and I don't know how to determine whether the input is a string or Boolean or integer or float. Here is that part of the code:

```
user_var = input("Please enter something: ")
print("you entered " + user_var)
print(type(user_var))
```

which always returns `str` for string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
from ast import literal_eval

def get_type(input_data):
    try:
        return type(literal_eval(input_data))
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        # A string, so return str
        return str

print(get_type("1"))        # <class 'int'>
print(get_type("1.2354"))   # <class 'float'>
print(get_type("True"))     # <class 'bool'>
print(get_type("abcd"))     # <class 'str'>
```

Comment: only Boolean values are still taken as strings. Any Idea?

Comment: @ApeironKambyses Do the boolean values have initial capital letters?

Answer (score 4):

[`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) will always return a string. If you want to see if it is possible to be converted to an integer, you should do:

```
try:
    int_user_var = int(user_var)
except ValueError:
    pass # this is not an integer
```

You could write a function like this:

```
def try_convert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                return bool(s)
            except ValueError:
                return s
```

However, as mentioned in the other answers, using `ast.literal_eval` would be a more concise solution.

Comment: do I have to use "if statements" to determine every single type and try to convert them to Booleans, floats etc?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do that.

Comment: `bool(s)` is `True` for every non-empty string. Without `literal_eval` you'd have to use a string comparison for `"True"` and `"False"`.

Answer (score 1):

Input will always return a string. You need to evaluate the string to get some Python value:

```
>>> type(eval(raw_input()))
23423
<type 'int'>
>>> type(eval(raw_input()))
"asdas"
<type 'str'>
>>> type(eval(raw_input()))
1.09
<type 'float'>
>>> type(eval(raw_input()))
True
<type 'bool'>
```

If you want safety (here user can execute arbitrary code), you should use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(raw_input()))
342
<type 'int'>
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(raw_input()))
"asd"
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: From the question `I'm using python 3.2.3`

Comment: This is very dangerous if the user input is `import os; os.system("rm -rf *")`.

Comment: @TomLeese no it's not, you are probably thinking of `exec` and not `eval`

Comment: Ok, you are correct that you would not be able to `import os`, but you could still run `os.system("rm -rf *")` if it was already imported.

Comment: @Tom Leese: see my edit. I didn't write it at first because I didn't remember in with module the `literal_eval` function was.

Comment: Thanks everybody. You all have been very helpful

Comment: `eval('__import__("os").listdir(".")')`. Don't use `eval`. Even if you use CPython's ability to set `__builtins__`, someone can always find a way back to `builtins`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that any input is taken a 'string'. So we need to treat 'string' as a special case, and keep it separate from everything else.

```
x = input("Enter something: ")

try:
    if type(eval(x)) == float:
        print(x, " is floating point number")
    elif type(eval(x)) == int:
        print(x, " is interger number")    
    elif type(eval(x)) == bool:
        print(x, " is a boolean")      
except:
    print("That is a string")
```

Here the input is first evaluated. If it's anything other than a string, the eval function shall show the type. If it's a string, it is considered as an "error", and the error message is given as "That is a string".