# Python 3 isinstance bool without external validator or type()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

so I'm trying to pass through a list and identify the different int, float, and bool. Now I'm aware after research from stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888620/python-comparing-boolean-and-int-using-isinstance) that bool is a subclass of int as per the initial Python versions and that I need some special handling to identify bool from int like so:

```
listone = ['232.54',False,'656',27.3,'5',' ',True,'-434','76.67','8.45','s',23]

for i in listone:
if isinstance(i,int):
    print(i,'INT')
elif isinstance(i,float):
    print(i,'FLOAT')
elif isinstance(i,str):
    print(i,'STR')

elif isinstance(i,bool):
    #SPECIAL HANDLING 
    print(i,'BOOL')
```

However even after doing so I still get the printout:

```
232.54 STR
False INT
656 STR
27.3 FLOAT
5 STR
STR
True INT
-434 STR
76.67 STR
8.45 STR
s STR
23 INT
```

Now, is there any way that I can get this printed out with some special handling, without using external validator like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199741/identifying-the-data-type-of-an-input) or by using "type() == "?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track to observe that `bool` is a subclass of `int`. The issue is the behavior of `isinstance`. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#isinstance) (emphasis added):

> **isinstance**(*object, classinfo*)
>
> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, ***or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof***. If
>   object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns
>   false. If classinfo is a tuple of type objects (or recursively, other
>   such tuples), return true if object is an instance of any of the
>   types. If classinfo is not a type or tuple of types and such tuples, a
>   TypeError exception is raised.

Since `bool` is a subclass of `int`, any bools passed into your if/elif clauses will not make it past the first if statement, `isinstance(<bool>, int)` will return `True`. You need to put the check for `bool` before the check for `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the order of your checks to check for `bool` first. That way it won't get caught by your check for `int`.

```
listone = ['232.54',False,'656',27.3,'5',' ',True,'-434','76.67','8.45','s',23]

for i in listone:

    if isinstance(i, bool):
        #SPECIAL HANDLING 
        print(i, 'BOOL')
    elif isinstance(i, int):
        print(i, 'INT')
    elif isinstance(i, float):
        print(i, 'FLOAT')
    elif isinstance(i, str):
        print(i, 'STR')
```