# How to identify different data types within a single column?

Tags: python, data-analysis, data-cleaning, data-quality

Let us say that we have a column with the following values:

Apple,
Mango,
Orange,
123,
987,
Guava,
01/01/2020

python recognizes this column as an "object" data type automatically.
I have been given a task to count the number of data types in a single column. 
For a human eye, it is evident that there are 3 data types in the above column values: string, int, date.
However, I am unable to come up with a code which could do this segregation.
Looking forward to the guidance!
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199741/identifying-the-data-type-of-an-input

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some code on what you have attempted? How are you setting up the data structure? Is it an m * n matrix where each column would have a common j in `data[i][j]`? In that case, it seems like you could just iterate over the matrix rows for the column and use the `type()` method.

Not knowing a bit more about your setup makes it difficult to provide a solution. Generally data in columns is of a common type.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in the form of a list, you could always do `list(map(type, list_name))` to return a list of types.