# How can I prove that a value from input is a number in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer

For a task I had to write a programm the programm functions nicely so I dont have a problem there. But I have to use input() and than I have to prove if the type is correct. I only needs integer but the type of input(5) is a str. Althought I need a int. But if use int(input()) thats also dont work because I want that my programm says this is a str or a float and because of this we cant move on. So that the programm now this is a number or not

I did try with only input() that were all Strings regardless of the content and i know why this is so but I dont like it. Then I tried int(input()) but this only works if I use actually only numbers. But I have also to type in strings and floats and then the programm should only say it is the wrong type but shouldnt print out an error message

Comment: `in = input()` then try to convert `in` to an integer. If it fails try to convert it to a floating point number, if it succeeds report it as such, otherwise report as invalid string.

Comment: As for catching conversion errors, read more about *exceptions*.

Comment: Read whatever format it is accepting & then typecast to int

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying the data type of an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199741/identifying-the-data-type-of-an-input)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can achieve this by using `eval` only.

e.g:

```
val = input()
try:
    val = eval(val)
except NameError:
    pass
```

In try it will try to return the exact data type, like int, float, bool, dict, and list will works fine but if input value is string it will go to NameError and print val is string.

if we want to handle some case on the basis of data type, we can do it using this:

```
if isinstance(val, int):
    print("This is integer")

if isinstance(val, float):
    print("This is float")

if isinstance(val, str):
    print("This is string")
```

similary for others as well.

Comment: Thank you this helps me a lot I guess I will use eval more often in the future now

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()


try:
    print(int(s))

except:
    print("not int")
```

Comment: It's better so specify what exception is expected. In this case ValueError

Comment: I just wanted to give him a simple example, but you are right

Comment: **do not use bare except clauses for this**